# How to limit append elements count in list

Tags: python, append, limit

An interesting problem that I'm trying to solve:

I need to limit count of employees I'm taking to expedition ( numbers in my code below )

***employee.txt*** example part:

> 30;electrical engineer;1;70
>
> 31;scientist;0;100
>
> 32;doctor;0;42
>
> 33;scientist;1;47
>
> 34;mechanic;0;63

I have the total number of each of them by gender and profession.
There is my code:

```
manager = 1
cook = 3
electrical_engineer = 4
computers_specialist = 5
doctor = 5
mechanic = 8
scientist = 14

expedition_total = 40
female_min = 21
male_min = 12

def total_resist_count():

    with open('employee.txt', 'r') as employee_list:

        total_count = 0
        female_count = 0
        male_count = 0
        expedition = []

        for employee in employee_list.readlines():
            employee_data = employee.rstrip().split(';')
            if int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                total_count += 1

            if int(employee_data[2] == '0') and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                female_count += 1

            if int(employee_data[2] == '1') and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                male_count += 1

        print('Stress-resistant colonists: ', total_count)
        print('--------- Female colonists: ', female_count)
        print('----------- Male colonists: ', male_count)
        print('--------------------------')
        print('Mars expedition list: ')
        pprint(expedition)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_resist_count()
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> Stress-resistant colonists:  90
>
> --------- Female colonists:  48
>
> ----------- Male colonists:  42
>
> ---
>
> Mars expedition list:
>
> []

And I need to add each of experts count to expedition ( limited to var's in code - 40 in total )

I try:

```
 if int(employee_data[2] == '0') and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
        expedition.append(employee_data)
        female_count += 1
```

And:

```
if int(employee_data[2] == '0') and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
            female_count += 1
            for female_employee in range(total_count - male_min):
                expedition.append(female_employee)
```

1) But I'm get full list of employees who have *employee_data[2] == '0'* and
*employee_data[3]) >= 60* ( obviously )

2) I get a duplicating numbers

> **How I can limit new list append to the numbers I needed ?**
>
> ***Appreciate any advices and pointing to mistakes***

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the numbers in employee.txt? And what sort of data are you wanting in the mars expedition list? Just a number? Or the full data? You could easily make a list of lists of data, each sublist representing an employee, if that's what you need.

Comment: if you print list witch contain those elements it will looks like:
[1,doctor,0,76] - id, occupation, gender, level, if you call employee_data[2] for this you will get '0'

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
manager = 1
cook = 3
electrical_engineer = 4
computers_specialist = 5
doctor = 5
mechanic = 8
scientist = 14

expedition_total = 40
female_min = 21
male_min = 12

    def total_resist_count():

        with open('employee.txt', 'r') as employee_list:

            total_count = 0
            female_count = 0
            male_count = 0
            expedition = []

            for employee in employee_list.readlines():
                employee_data = employee.rstrip().split(';')
                if int(employee_data[2] == 0) and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                    female_count += 1
                    total_count += 1
                    expedition.append(employee_data)

                elif int(employee_data[2] == 1) and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                    male_count += 1
                    total_count += 1
                    expedition.append(employee_data)

        print('Stress-resistant colonists: ', total_count)
        print('--------- Female colonists: ', female_count)
        print('----------- Male colonists: ', male_count)
        print('--------------------------')
        print('Mars expedition list: ')
        print(expedition)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        total_resist_count()
```

If you need more specific parameters, add them in the conditional statements. Like if you need a minimum/maximum amount of a certain type of employee, just check if the running total of this type of employee is within the bounds and if it is, then append or ignore accordingly.

if you have a maximum amount of people you can take (40), use:

```
manager = 1
cook = 3
electrical_engineer = 4
computers_specialist = 5
doctor = 5
mechanic = 8
scientist = 14

expedition_total = 40
female_min = 21
male_min = 12

total_count = 0
female_count = 0
male_count = 0
expedition = []

    def total_resist_count():
        global total_count
        global female_count
        global male_count
        global expedition

        with open('employee.txt', 'r') as employee_list:
            while len(expedition) < total_count:

                for employee in employee_list.readlines():
                    employee_data = employee.rstrip().split(';')
                    if int(employee_data[2] == '0') and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                        female_count += 1
                        total_count += 1
                        expedition.append(employee_data)

                    elif int(employee_data[2] == '1') and int(employee_data[3]) >= 60:
                        male_count += 1
                        total_count += 1
                        expedition.append(employee_data)

        print('Stress-resistant colonists: ', total_count)
        print('--------- Female colonists: ', female_count)
        print('----------- Male colonists: ', male_count)
        print('--------------------------')
        print('Mars expedition list: ')
        print(expedition)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        total_resist_count()
```

Comment: this just add all 120 employees I have in total for expedition

Comment: edited to account for this. i can help if you need to have certain numbers of certain types of employees too, not just the first 40 employees listed

Comment: Be more specific about other parameters and i can continue to help